# Eclipse Freeze On Autocomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

The problem has appeared Eclipse 2019-09.  I write some code without any problem. Sometimes, I write code and press ctrl+space and eclipse halting and not responding. How i can I solve this problem?

**Edit:** I found this error in eclipse log;

*!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-10-14 13:44:08.997
 !MESSAGE Failed to download org.eclipse.recommenders:index::zip:0.0.0
 !STACK 0*

**Edit 2:** I found 'Code Recommenders' cause this error. reinstall eclipse and jboss tools without recommenders. solved the problem !

Comment: Editing what language? With which editor?

Comment: Using Java. default editor